# boost::multi_index like container in rust

Tags: c++, rust, multi-index

I'm C++ programmer. I try to port some C++ program that uses boost::multi_index container to Rust.

https://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

The C++ code uses multi_index to erase the element by O(1) complexity from the all indexes by the iterator that is gotten by one index. That is important point.

Is there any good way to do that using Rust?

I couldn't find a container that supports multiple indexes in the standard library.

Comment: I found https://github.com/pandaman64/MultiIndexContainer but it seems that it isn't completed and maintained.

Comment: It seems that https://github.com/lun3x/multi_index_map is something exactly I want to have. It has been published June 2022. I will try it.

Comment: When I used boost multi index 10 years ago its delete performance was so bad I had to learn how to use boost intrusive - so glad to hear it is now O(1), will await your report on rust findings

Comment: iterator_to() can extract iterator from value_type. Then we can use it for erasing. I guess that the same approach is used internal removal. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/ord_indices.html#iterators